# What is the right mkfs cli in order to create xfs file-system on huge disk

Tags: disk, xfs, mkfs, hadoop, kafka

We need to create `xfs` file-system on  `kafka` disk

The special thing about `kafka` disk is the disk size

`kafka` disk have `20TB` size in our case

I not sure about the following `mkfs` , but I need advice to understand if the following cli , is good enough to create `xfs` file system on huge disk ( `kafka` machine )

```
 DISK=sdb
 mkfs.xfs -L kafka  /dev/$DISK -f
```

**kafka best practice**

> FileSystem Selection
>   Kafka uses regular files on disk, and such it has no hard dependency on a specific file system.
>   We recommend EXT4 or XFS. Recent improvements to the XFS file system have shown it to have the better performance characteristics for Kafka’s workload without any compromise in stability.
>   Note: Do not use mounted shared drives and any network file systems. In our experience Kafka is known to have index failures on such file systems. Kafka uses MemoryMapped files to store the offset index which has known issues on a network file systems.

Comment: isn't syntax `mkfs -t xfs ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you cited:

> The XFS filesystem [...] does not require any change in the default settings, either at filesystem creation time or at mount.

Source: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#xfs

So it should just work. Also there is nothing special anymore about a 20TB device size.

Consider adding a partition table and then use `/dev/sdb1` instead of `/dev/sdb`.